# Go Daddy SSL certificate disappear in IIS After Installing

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, web-hosting, godaddy-api

I am trying to install the SSL certificate on the IIS, I am following the exact step mentioned here https://pk.godaddy.com/help/manually-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-my-iis-10-server-27349.

Steps I did:

- I purchased the SSL certificate from Go Daddy
- I configured that on Go Daddy by giving the domain name
- Submit the changes for getting the certificate
- After verification downloaded the certificate
- Created .Cer file from the .crt file
- Imported the gd-g2_iis_intermediates.p7b in MMC under the intermediate certificate authority
- Create a request in IIS and import .Cer file
- After refreshing that window, the certificate doesn't appear

Am I doing something wrong in this?

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-whole-story-of-server-certificate-disappears-in-iis-7-7-5-8-8-5-10-0-after-installing-it-why-b66e802baa38 You cannot import a certificate without its private key merged.

Answer (score 0):

So the thing is I was facing an issue because I couldn't able to produce the .pfx file from my machine using MMC, but DigiCert tool helped me to create the .pfx file from the .crt file I got from the Go Daddy. Instructions to create the file are on this link

https://www.digicert.com/kb/util/pfx-certificate-management-utility-import-export-instructions.htm

Later I went to the MMC and to the intermediate certificate authority and I imported the .pfx file along with the password and the certificate got exported to the system and to the IIS and now it's visible in the IIS.